# Removing Rows in dataframe based on set of rules

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df in R which has 6 columns but for my explaination I will use an example to make it easier to explain my need.

So example dataframe is looking like this:

```
APPELANT DURATION

A 1

B 0

B 2

C 3

D 4

E 0

E 0

E 0

E 5

F 0

F 0

C 6

A 0

A 7
```

Now I want to have a dataframe as follows:

```
APPELANT DURATION

A 1

B 2

C 3

D 4

E 5 

F 0

C 6

A 7
```

However whenever I tried to do this I always end up with for each lettre to highest duration. But when the letters are not following eachother I need to keep them all.
In words, I just want to remove the preeciding 0s when in a next row the duration becomes more than 0, as zero's indicate that a call is being transferred but sometimes there is only a 0 which means the call is not answered at all, I don't know if this is enough information... it is difficult to explain in text only. A caller can call back at a later time and we need both durations then, this call can be missed twice or be answerd twice or answerd and missed. So to write a code that is taking this all into account is very difficult for me.

I hope someone can help me with this as it is killing me that I am not able to solve this problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to `summarise` your data frame so that it contains the `last` row for each `consecutive_id` of `APPELANT`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(ID = consecutive_id(APPELANT)) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), last), .by = ID) %>%
  select(-ID)
#>   APPELANT DURATION
#> 1        A        1
#> 2        B        2
#> 3        C        3
#> 4        D        4
#> 5        E        5
#> 6        F        0
#> 7        C        6
#> 8        A        7
```

---

**Question data in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(APPELANT = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "E", "E", 
                                  "E", "E", "F", "F", "C", "A", "A"), 
                     DURATION = c(1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L,
                                  0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 7L)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as it is working on the example data, for my complete set there are no rows deleted. you might have an idea why this is?

Nvm, did something wrong lets check the code in more detail now ;)

Comment: Yes, there _are_ rows deleted - the summary frame is shorter than the initial data. Perhaps you have cases where the same Appelant makes two consecutive calls, and the second one is deleted? - the above code would not handle this without extra tweaks. Difficult to know for sure without seeing the actual data that is causing the problem @user21699241

Comment: @user21699241  I have now modified it so that consecutive calls by the same appelant are handled.

Comment: Okay almost perfect, now I want to add to keep the other columns but without changing the results. 

df_new <- df %>%
  mutate(ID = consecutive_id(APPELANT)) %>%
  group_by(ID, DATES, HEURE, APPELANT, APPELÉ, DÉCROCHÉ) %>%
  summarise(DURATION = max(DURATION)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-ID)

but whenever I do this it is also taking into account the other columns so if they are different it is keeping the rows, but it should ignore the other columns for this check?

Comment: @user21699241 no, you can't group by all those columns. See my update for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `rle` + `subset`

```
subset(
    df,
    ave(
        !DURATION,
        with(rle(APPELANT), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)),
        FUN = \(x) seq_along(x) == length(x)
    )
)
```

gives

```
   APPELANT DURATION
1         A        1
3         B        2
4         C        3
5         D        4
9         E        5
11        F        0
12        C        6
14        A        7
```